# CommunityGraphPlot of weighted graph: node too far

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am playing with weighted `Graph` and `CommunityGraphPlot`, and I am considering the following example.

```
listWeights = {2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
tab = {UndirectedEdge[3, 1], UndirectedEdge[3, 31], UndirectedEdge[3, 32], UndirectedEdge[3, 33], Table[UndirectedEdge[1, i + 1], {i, 1, 29}]} // Flatten
g = Graph[tab[[All]], EdgeWeight -> Normalize@listWeights]
```

which reproduce the following `Graph`

[image]

When I use the `CommunityGraphPlot` to find the communities

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g, ImageSize -> Full, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

I get

[image]

**Question:** why is the node `2` plotted so far? You can see from the code that it has an unormalized weight of 2, so I was expecting it closest to the node `1`.

Comment: Please show a *minimal* example. Do the weights matter in any way?

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for the comment. With minimal examples I don't see this behaviour, otherwise I would have posted the most minimal one :) The weights should matter, no? For example, if I set some `0` weight, then I get a different communities plot, where the nodes that have 0 weight with the node `1` generate a separate community.

Comment: "The weights should matter, no?" Have you actually *tried* it, or are you just assuming this? I just tried omitting them and it nothing changed.

Comment: @Szabolcs try to set listWeights = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
   2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

Comment: Why? I thought your question was: "why is the node 2 plotted so far?" Does it matter for that?

Comment: BTW this is very likely a glitch in the graph layout algorithm (maybe not enough iterations performed) and the weights have no bearing on it. Weights will affect community detection, but not graph plotting (unless you explicitly turn this on, which I do not know how to do for CommunityGraphPlot; I can only do it for Graph)

Comment: @Szabolcs So, the weights matter for community detection through `FindGraphCommunities`?

Comment: Also, I would be very careful with community detection in Mathematica. There is next to no information about what `FindGraphCommunities` does internally, only a few very vague hints. There is no information about how weights are used, and whether they represent stronger or "longer" (weaker) ties.  When you write up your paper with your results, basically your only choice is to say "this was computed with version X of Mathematica, I have no idea how, and I have no idea how weights were used".

Comment: This is why I exposed igraph's community detection functions in [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM). They are far from perfect, but at least they are relatively well documented and they all come with references to the papers that describe the implemented community detection methods. You *should* have at least a basic understanding of these methods and how they do or do not use weights, so looking up the papers is highly recommended.

Comment: @Szabolcs ok, so this partially answer my question. I have not understood how the weights are used, and I had the natural expectation that closers nodes corresponds to highest weights.

Comment: Just be cautious, test instead of just assuming, and if in doubt, ask Wolfram Support ... I have mixed experiences with asking them about this specific topic, and I am very frustrated by the lack of proper documentation on it.  If you have questions about IGraph/M, you can ask me (perhaps use the IGraph/M chatroom)